# How do I get root view of list_view_item.xml inside ListView adapter?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a ListView items/cell that has a few layers, relative, linearLayout etc.
I tried doing v.getParent() inside the onClick of the button but it just went one layer up.  How can I get a reference to the root of the current element inside onClick event handler?

Here is my getView()

```
             Button v = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);

             v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                     onClick(View v) {

                        //Right here I want to find another view inside the cell.
                        View otherView = ???.findViewById(R.id.myOtherViewInListItem); 
                             otherView.setBackgroundColor(...);
                        .........................................
                     } 
              });
```

Comment: Thats a great answer! I'll probably be posting an answer myself to this question in a bit so time is running out ...

Comment: Thanks anyway Daniel!  Next time you ask a question I'm sure everyone will answer!

Comment: It worked!  I feel better now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm imagining that this button is inside the ListView element. Based on this assumption:

1. create only one OnClickListener. The way you're doing you're creating `adapter.getCount()` OnClick listener and waste memory like crazy.
2. Maybe you want to completely remove the button and use the OnItemClick to track clicks on your whole ListView element, this will pass to you the reference to the whole View.
3. If you really must have the button, inside your getView you store a reference to the parent, something like that:

   ```
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // do whatever you're doing to get the view, let's call it v
       Button b = (Button)v.findViewById(/* your button id */ )
       b.setTag(v)
   }
   ```

then on your click listener you can:

```
    onClic(View v){
        View parent = (View)b.getTag();
    }
```

and if that answer works for you (I know it does) accept it as correct like Daniel Martinus pointed out.

Comment: yes, but I think v.getRootView() will go all the way to the top.  Then use that view to find it.

Comment: But if it's an adapter, it's being inflated from XML an all the views have the same ID, so how will you find it? I'll tell you how, with the answer I just posted.

Comment: on b.setTag(v) you should have posted b.setTag(convertView) etc.  Watch that syntax Budius!

Comment: On closer inspection I think you are correct.  It is necessary to keep track of specific associated view.

Comment: the code comment clearly states `// do whatever you're doing to get the view, let's call it v`, I'm telling you that I'm calling it `v` and that you have to adapt to whatever you're using.

Comment: I have a companion question coming up. Stay tuned!

Comment: Here it is! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950970/how-to-prevent-modified-listview-item-from-being-reused-or-at-least-not-before

Answer (score 0):

```
 Inside onClick(View v)

just call v.getViewParent();  then you will have a view from which you can call the find for   the others.
```

Comment: there is no such method `v.getViewParent()`.